# How to test if Xamarin Android app closes

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I am writing my first Android app, using Xamarin. I have an Exit button that, when clicked, closes the app. I want a test in Xamarin UITest that verifies clicking the button closes the app. I messed around with it for a while and finally found something that allows the test to pass.

In the app:

```
exitButton.Click += (o, e) =>
{
    int pid = Android.OS.Process.MyPid();
    Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(pid);
};
```

In UITest:

```
[Test]
public void ExitButtonClosesTheScreen()
{
    try
    {
        app.Tap(c => c.Button("exitButton"));
        Assert.Fail("App remains open.");
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.", e.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

The test now passes so I guess I'm happy. My question is, is this really the best way to do this? Or is there a better way that I wasn't able to find?

Edit: Unfortunately, this is not the answer. This method allows the test to pass in VS but fails when I run it in App Center. Is there another way to run this test? Or is this something that is simply not testable with UITest? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ben, This seems to be the right way of doing it but your question could be sort of opinion based anyway you are doing it right

Comment: @G.hakim Thank you for answering. Unfortunately my way doesn't work in App Center. I've edited the question to reflect this. So, to your knowledge, there is no other way to write such a test? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the right code for closing the Application as per me is using finish affinity

**In an Activity:**

```
this.FinishAffinity();
```

**In a Fragment:**

```
this.Activity.FinishAffinity();
```

After doing this AppCenter should be able to figure that your app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I did a brief read up on this the other day for something similar and I am certain that the ActivityManager class would be the best way to go about this. 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.ActivityManager/

There is a method within this class called RunningAppProcesses which returns a list of application processes that are running on the device - and from there I guess you can assert if your app process is on the list or not.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After almost 4 years, i've encountered with the same issue.

I will do it this way in your case:

```
[Test]
public void ExitButtonClosesTheScreen()
{
  app.Tap(c => c.Marked("exitButton"));

  /** I asume exitButton click action will just exit, 
    no popups or alerts appear before exiting. **/

  app.WaitForNoElement(q => q.Marked("exitButton"), 
      "Timeout waiting for element exitButton", 
      new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));

  AppResult[] result = app.Query();
  Assert.IsTrue(result.Length == 0);
}
```

app.Query() returns all views visible by default, unless a query is especified by a lambda expression, as you should alredy know.

If the Application is gone, the Views visible will be 0, and as such, app.query() will return and array lenght of 0.

For WaitForNoElement's timeout I use a TimeSpan of 30 seconds, but you can use whatever timeout you prefer for this operation, i just considered 30 seconds will be ok.